# ruby, selenium webdriver, click each name in table column

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have table that list rows, the first column has names as links :
[image]

How to click on each name, go to the next page do something, come back and click the next name until you finish all of them ?
Thanks.

Comment: Include the HTML of the table please!

Comment: https://justpaste.it/6r2km

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume only one table in your page or I assume the given table is the first table. If it's not then, we first have to locate the table.

This code will work for you. If Table first row is header which doesn't consist of link, then use from index 2 `.with_index(2)` If table first row consist of link, then use from index 1 as shown below.

```
driver.find_elements(xpath: "//table//tr").each_with_index  do |_,index|
  next if index.eql?0
  driver.find_element(xpath: "//table//tr[#{index}]/td[1]/a").click
  driver.navigate.back
end
```

Comment: thanks for the code, I did not work Friday, just test it, but it does not work, I got :       Unable to locate element: //table//tr[3]/td[1]/a (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Comment: the filter returned only two rows, I don't know why the index is still searching for the third row (index 3)

Comment: @Fatna, so it clicked first two rows?

Comment: @Fatna Okay, then you header for the table which is non-editable?

Comment: @Fatna Is it clicking the first two rows? It is failing when you reach third row?

Comment: It's clicking the first two rows, it's failing to reach the third row because it does not exist, they are only two rows.

Comment: @Fatna I think your table consist of header, I updated the code, try with this one, let me know whether it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169594/discussion-between-fatna-and-rajagopalan).